# Httpclient Cookie Issue

Tags: c#, cookies, uwp, win-universal-app, session-cookies

Issue: I am trying to use httpclient for fetching data from a site.Now the site requires you to first visit a link then only you can post data to the next link.
Link1 is  a simple get request 
Link2 is a post request 
Now I think the site first store some cookie from the link1 and then only allow you to post data to link2 as whenever I try to open the link2 in incognito the site displays the error message "**Session Timed out OR Maximum connections limit reached. Cannot Proceed Further. Please close and restart your browser** "
 Now I have tried this:

```
 try
        {
            //Send the GET request
            httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(link1UriString));
            //Send the POSTrequest
             httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(link2uriString),postContent);                
            httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
```

But I am getting the session timed out error message. How to maintain cookies for a session in httpClient continuously received from the web.Like in python it can be done by

```
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
 urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

[Link1](http://115.248.50.60/registration/Main.jsp?wispId=1&nasId=00:15:17:c8:09:b1)
[Link2](http://115.248.50.60/registration/chooseAuth.do)

Comment: Is this VIT Wi-Fi :P. Also did you complete this? Im trying to do the same and need help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CookieContainer` to handle cookies for you.
Doing so, you'd create the HttpClient like this.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(link1UriString));
```

(Note it uses the version of HttpClient in System.Net.Http)

Comment: Great, I forgot about `CookieContainer` :), Your answer more elegant

Comment: Hey @Matt Kacey thanks for your answer.Now the data i need to post contains a integer and a string but the FormurlEncodedContent only accept string values any idea how to post this data using httpClinet.PostAsync() or by any other methods

Comment: @Uwpbeginner does this answer not work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41620514/1755

Comment: Thx,but I want use Web.http.

Answer (score 1):

So, after first response you have `Set-Cookie` header:

```
var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://115.248.50.60/registration/Main.jsp?wispId=1&nasId=00:15:17:c8:09:b1");
IEnumerable<string> values;
var coockieHeader = string.Empty;
if (responseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("set-cookie", out values))
{
    coockieHeader = string.Join(string.Empty, values);
}
```

After that, just setup your cookie into request message:

```
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://115.248.50.60/registration/chooseAuth.do"),
            Content = postContent,
            Method = HttpMethod.Post
        };

        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", values);
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

Comment: Hey @Andrii Krupka thanks for your answer but Matt's  method was simpler to implement.